I keep encountering an error when cross-compiling lmbench-3.0-a9 with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. Can someone help me with this?
make OS=arm-linux CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar build
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ltirpc: No such file or directory
I tried to install -ltirpc, but it seems that it still didn't work.

When you say "tried to install [lib]tirpc", what exactly did you do ?
Usually on most Linux distributions, to be able to link against a library, you need to install the -dev or -devel package for a given library. The lib alone is not sufficient for the linker to find it.
